# Accessing subfields in template

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I'm using autoform with simple schema and collection2 and I've created a schema with subfields. I'm having trouble accessing the subfields in my template. I seem to just get [object object]. The subfields are arrays. Can someone tell me what I'm missing.

Path: `template.html`

```
{{#with currentUser}}
    {{#with profile}}                   
            {{#each CV}}
                {{languages}}   
            {{/each}}    
    {{/with}}           
{{/with}}
```

Path: `schema.js`

```
Schema.Language = new SimpleSchema({
    language: {
        type: String,  
        optional: true    
    },
    proficiency: {
        type: String,  
        optional: true    
    }
});

Schema.CV = new SimpleSchema({
    languages: {
        type: [Schema.Language],
        optional: true
    }
});

Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
    CV: {
        type: Schema.CV,
        optional: true,
    },
});

Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
    profile: {
        type: Schema.UserProfile,
        optional: true
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Schema.Language` has several properties, which means it's an object.  Try this:

```
{{#with currentUser}}
    {{#with profile}}                   
            {{#each CV}}
                {{#each languages}}  
                    {{language}}
                {{/each}} 
            {{/each}}    
    {{/with}}           
{{/with}}
```

You also could replace the `#each CV` with a `#with` operator, as CV is not an array in your schema.

Comment: THANKS! When I used your code and changed #each to #with it worked. Thanks again. Sorry for the delayed response, my partner had a baby so I've been a little preoccupied. Thanks again.